# Question on formatting dates as text in excel

Tags: excel

I have two sets of data. One has dates in the format Jan 10, 2020 which is stored as text. The other format is dd/mm/yyyy and is not text.

I'm trying to check if the dates are equal but I can't get it to work.

I've removed the , in the text stored date. I've tried using the Datevalue function but it just returns #value. The date function also doesn't work...

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If I copy the string "Jan 10, 2020" into Excel, it automatically converts it to a date format. Have you tried changing the format of the cell to "Date"? Using `DATEVALUE` also works fine on my machine.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad the format of the cell is set to General. If I change it to a date format, visually the data in the cell remains exactly the same. If I then use datevalue I just get a #value. The only function that seems to work is ISTEXT which returns true. I'm not sure if its some weird issue with regional settings?

Comment: It might very well be the regional settings, FYI, I am running with US English settings

Comment: My regional settings should be UK English settings. Any idea how to check if it is the regional settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all text strings are suitable for DateValue(). It works best when the day, month and year representation are in the order that your regional settings expect. If you are on UK settings, then you want DMY order, but the date text is in MDY order.

Therefore, you need to transform the text string into something that Datevalue() can process, for example

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,5,FIND(",",A1)-5)&"-"&LEFT(A1,3)&"-"&RIGHT(A1,4))
```

This formula works for one- or two-digit days.

[image]

Format the result as date and use it for your comparison.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks, I wasn't aware of that about Datevalue function! I did try your method but as mdy previously.